# How does Google Analytics track session expiration?

Tags: session, cookies, google-analytics, web-analytics

The GA documentation, which was updated quite recently clearly states that GA uses a _utmb cookie, which is set by default to 30 minutes to track when a session expires:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

I have inspected several websites, some of them our own, which use GA and none of them have this cookie. So I am wondering does Google Analytics still use a cookie to track session expiration or they have switched to some other mechanism?

I am asking because I am developing an website tracking script, which also needs to track sessions. Therefore referring to GA seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closer you will notice that the _utmb cookies appears under the headline "ga.js – cookie usage". So this refers to the legacy version of Google Analytics.

The current Universal Analytics (analytics.js) does not use cookies to keep track of sessions other than that it uses a cookie to store the client id. Session expiration is calculated on the server (per default 30 minutes inactivity, change of traffic attribution data or more than 500 interactions for the same client id).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed to know, if the session is calculated on the server.

Comment: Are there any obvious disadvantages of tracking the session expiration via a cookie, in other words on the client side because of which GA might have decided against it?